# EZAudio CocoaPods module import error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, ezaudio

When adding EZAudio to my swift project using CocoaPods, I get a compiler error that says:
`Could not build Objective-C module 'EZAudio'`

My Podfile is this:

```
platform :ios, '9'
use_frameworks!

pod 'CorePlot'
pod 'SWRevealViewController'
pod 'EZAudio'
```

I add it to a swift file like so:

```
import EZAudio
```

I am not using a bridging header. Does anybody have any insight into why this is happening?

Comment: Can you please help me I am getting same issue.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is in the `EZAudioiOS.m` and `EZAudioOSX.m` files. You can find those in: `/Pods/EZAudio/Core/EZAudioiOS.m`

**Change the following lines:**

```
#import <EZAudioiOS/EZAudio.h>
```

**With:**

```
#import "EZAudio.h"
```

An alert will popup, to Unlock the file, you are editing. Just click "Unlock".

Comment: I tried to change above file. But still getting same issue cant import module in Swift 3.

Comment: This happened to me but I also had to change `#import <EZAudioOSX/EZAudio.h>1` to `#import "EZAudio.h"`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to add `pod 'TPCircularBuffer'` to the Podfile as well. Works fine now.